# raw-graphs color by column

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

Im dabling in [rawgraphs.io](http://app.rawgraphs.io/) and wonder if I can somehow set color of objects directly via a column imported. Lets say I have a csv as follows:

**Country**-----**City**------------**Color**
Sweden-----Stockholm---#c6c6c6
Spain--------Barcelona----#ffffff

If I then choose a circle packing diagram and sort by city, is there any possibility to now set "Stockholm" to the color #c6c6c6 and Barcelona to the color #ffffff as dictated by the column?

What I found is the function `scope.setColor = function(key, color)` but to use this I would need to access the correct key and color from my parsed document, how can I access my parsed elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a duplicate of this other question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141424/dictate-colors-via-column-in-rawgraph-d3).

Anyway, there is no such feature now, if you believe it is useful, open a [issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/densitydesign/raw/issues).