# Dictate colors via column in rawgraph/d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When creating a rawgraph (http://rawgraphs.io) is there any way I can have a column in my document that dictates the colors of the representing bar/bubble or however I chose to represent my data?

An example document could look like

```
Gender  -   Age   -    Color  
Male    -   23    -    blue  
female  -   17    -    red
```

So the color on the generated graph gets dicated by the color column

Comment: Are your tags right? D3 can do that, sure. But rawgraph? No idea, sorry. Have you tried asking their Google group?

Answer (score 1):

Colours are generated by RAWGraphs using an ordinal scale (from d3.js) picking from a pre-existing palette, so there is no way for dictating the colours from a data table.

Anyway, you could map the colours on specific values, export an SVG and change them afterwards within a vector graphics editor (Adobe Illustrator lets you select object by fill/stroke colour) or, more tricky, with a text editor performing a find-and-replace for all the hexadecimal values.

If you think the colour dictation is a useful feature, try to [open a issue on GitHub](https://github.com/densitydesign/raw/issues).